Angular How to change related components style when hovering an element that is not a direct sibling
I'm not sure if using rxjs is the best way to achieve this.
Imagine that you have some text, each word is a component and unfortunately these components are not all direct siblings. A word or group of words can have an annotation component like a number above the text, just like in books. When hovering the annotation I need to change the style of its related word, other than itself of course. Also if I hover words, the annotation should change its style, again and the words themselves too.
I tried with a common service and using subjects etc, but I end up having that all word and all annotation component instances listen to all the subject.next calls and each component instance need to filter the incoming event by some id. When there is a lot of components, it starts becoming slow.
Should one use input parameters to do this via state management on a parent component instead?
Sorry for not being able to provide some code example. This is simplified quite a bit, in the word.component:
onHover() {
   this.hoverService.hoveredWord$.next(this.word.id);
}

In the annotation.component:
shouldHighlight$ = combineLatest([
    this.onAnnotationHover$, // this is called inside this component with this.onAnnotationHover.next()
    this.hoverService.hoveredWord$,
]).pipe(
   map(([hover, word]) => hover || this.annotationData.includes(word));

And viceversa for hovering annotations and then observing on the word component.
I guess what I'm asking rather than specific code, if there is a better way to do this.

Why is this markup? Each word a component? Why not trying to achieve all visual effects with style (css)?

Rather than the component filtering itself, can you instead register the component so that it only gets streams for the related changes? that should help for the performance issue

@MoxxiManagarm that would be great, I'm not sure what you mean in the implementation.

@BennyHalperin the code is too complex to change that much, the word component is wrapped by other components that change how words are rendered, these are instanciate dynamically based on the data that arrives from various sources. I joined this project later on.

Another approach would be to use a single directive that is then bound to all word elements and uses renderer2 to apply/remove the html  for that word element when its annotation is clicked?

You can get it only using .css
Imagine you have some like
<parent>
   <group-word>
     <word>
       <anotation></anotation>
     </word>
     <word>
       <anotation></anotation>
     </word>
   </group-word>
</parent>

From parent you can use .css
[group-word] [word] [anotation] span:hover{
    color:red;
}

